# Text wont align on second Nav bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to make a second navigation bar on my homepage the same as http://www.adventurelink.com/Gallery/Destination.com.

I have the first (top nav bar & text) in place but the text (links) for the second only sits underneath and I'm not sure why as I copy and pasted the code changing the "id" names. At the moment I'm just setting the layout before adding real content but need to sort this first. Any help would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>website</title>

            <link href="file:///C|/Users/Deniz/Desktop/Website/css/2nd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

        <body>
<!--TOP NAVIGATION BAR AND LOGO-->
            <div id="topnavbar">
            <div id="logo"></div>
                <nav id="topnavlinks">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
<!--SPACE FOR CHANGING PICTURES-->
            <div id="picspace"></div>
<!--BOTTOM NAVIGATION BAR-->
            <div id="botnavbar"></div>
                <nav id="botnavlinks">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html">Activities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html">Things to do</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html">Accomodation</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#.html">Transport</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </nav>
<!--CONTENT---->
            <div id="content"></div>
<!--FOOTER-->
            <div id="footer"></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
 * {
margin:0px;
}
#topnavbar{
height:50px;
margin:0 auto;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e78869, #ad4e2f); /* For Safari */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#e78869, #ad4e2f); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#e78869, #ad4e2f); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#e78869, #ad4e2f); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
#topnavlinks{
    width:500px;
float:right;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#topnavlinks ul{
margin: 0 auto;
list-style:none;
height:35px;
}
#topnavlinks li{
margin: 0 auto;
height:35px;
float:left;
}
#topnavlinks li a:link, a:visited{
display:block;
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#topnavlinks li a:hover{
background-color:#6880af;
}
#logo{
}
#picspace{
height:400px;
background-color:grey;
}
#botnavbar{
height:50px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#6880af, #314a79); /* For Safari */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#6880af, #314a79); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#6880af, #314a79); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#6880af, #314a79); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
#botnavlinks{
width:500px;
float:right;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#botnavlinks ul{
margin: 0 auto;
list-style:none;
height:35px;
}
#botnavlinks li{
margin: 0 auto;
height:35px;
float:left;
}
#botnavlinks li a:link, a:visited{
display:block;
color:black;
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
}
#botnavlinks li a:hover{
background-color:#e78869;
}
#content{
height:500px;
background-color:grey;
}
#footer{
}
```

Comment: what do you mean my link?

Comment: He means the link you provided is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still going to need a lot more styling but the reason for this is because in your `botnavbar` you closed the div before you put the links in it.

```
<!--BOTTOM NAVIGATION BAR-->
        <div id="botnavbar"></div>  <!-- here, this shouldn't be closed yet -->
            <nav id="botnavlinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Things to do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Accomodation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Transport</a></li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
```

You created the "botnavbar" and immediately closed that div, so the links aren't going to be inside that bar. Just move the `</div>` down.

```
<!--BOTTOM NAVIGATION BAR-->
        <div id="botnavbar">
            <nav id="botnavlinks">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="destinations.html">Destinations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Activities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Things to do</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Accomodation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#.html">Transport</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
         </div>
```